# struct containing string value causes segmentation fault upon its assignment after its creation using dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++, string, memory-management, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

The compiler throws runtime segfault upon following code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
  int data;
  void *next;   
  string nodeType;
};

Node* initNode(int data){
  Node *n = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
  n->data = data;
  n->next = NULL;
  n->nodeType = "Node";   //if this line is commented it works else segfault
  return n;
}

int main() {
  Node *n1 = initNode(10);
  cout << n1->data << endl;
}
```

Can someone please explain why string assignment does not work inside a struct which is dynamically allocated where in case of static allocation why it works ?

where as the following way it works :

```
Node initNode(string data){
  Node n;
  n.data = data;  //This works for node creation statically
  n.next = NULL;
  n.nodeType = "Node";  //and even this works for node creation statically
  return n;
}
```

and then in the main function:

```
int main() {
  Node n2 = initNode("Hello");
  cout << n2.data << endl;
}
```

Comment: `malloc` just allocates memory, it doesn't *construct* the object instance, which means the `string` constructor is not called.

Comment: General rule of thumb : don't use C's `malloc` in C++, use `new`, and actually don't use `new` either if possible, and use `make_shared` or `std::unique_ptr` (C++11)

Answer (score 8):

This doesn't work because you don't actually construct a `Node` instance into the memory which you `malloc`.

You should use `new` instead:

```
Node *n = new Node{};
```

`malloc` only allocates memory, it has no idea what a class is or how to instantiate one. You should generally not use it in C++.

`new` allocates memory *and* constructs an instance of the class.

Comment: Hey yaa this works:
Node *n = new Node();

But i thought that malloc would actually allocate memory by creating instance ? Isn't that true ? can you please explain or provide pointers to difference between doing "new" and "malloc"  and when to use it ?

Comment: yup right!  thanks! well I actually had a feeling that the string's constructor would be called when I did malloc as it was string and not string*

Comment: `malloc` doesn't call any constructors of any members of your class.

Answer (score 4):

There is no place, where std::string constructor is executed.

You should use new

```
example *e = new example;
```

or placement new

```
void *example_raw = malloc(sizeof(example));
example *e = new(example_raw) example;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 Node *n = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

This cast is nonsense. You can't just tell the compiler to pretend that a chunk of data you just allocate contains a valid `Node` object and then manipulate it.

Comment: yup right!  well I actually had a feeling that the string's constructor would be called when I did malloc as it was string and not string* inside the Node

Answer (score 1):

`string` in c++ is an class and to create string objects use `new` instead of malloc as below .

```
Node *n = new Node{};
```